# Angular Material cross component data transmitting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to accomplish something which could easily be accomplished with a Global variable in any database management system.

I trying to pass data from one component to another, via a service.  The components could be described as siblings which are in the components folder, and the service is in a services folder which is a sibling of the components folder.

The component in the statususers folder should be emiting data to a component in the hours folder via a service.

The service is very simple:

```
    import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core'                  ;
    import { EventEmitter }   from '@angular/core'                  ;
    import { Subject }        from 'rxjs/Subject'                   ;
    import { Statususers }    from '../models/statususers.model'    ;

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'                                  ;

    @Injectable()
    export class CribsService 
    {
      aircraftSelected = new EventEmitter<Statususers>()  ;  
    }
```

And it receives data from the statususers component from this code.

```
   this.cribsService.aircraftSelected.emit(this.statususers)   ;
```

Since I am so new at this, I feel that the problem is that the service is not getting the data which should be emitted in the code immediately above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your components you should subscribe to cribsService.aircraftSelected

```
 this.cssub = this.cribsService.aircraftSelected.subscribe((statususers:Statususers) => {//do something with statususers});
```

In order to avoid memory leaks in ngOnDestroy method remember to unsubscribe:

```
this.cssub.unsubscribe();
```

Take a look at this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tszppv)

Comment: Thanks for the tip for the ngOnDestroy.

Comment: Still having an issue, You will notice there is an 'alert' but nothing is ever displayed.  It seems to me that the 'emitter' is not doing it's job.

Comment: please update your question, not my answer, you should provide a complete example with the issue on stackblitz